# Shopify Liquid If condition isn't working within nested loop

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm trying to use the following nested for loop. But it seems like not working.

```
 {% for col_id in (1..5) -%}
          {% for block in section.blocks %}
            {%- liquid
              assign current_col = col_id
              assign position = block.settings.position
              assign col_position = block.settings.col_position
              
            -%}
            {% comment %} Render block content {% endcomment %}
            {%- if position == index -%}
              <p
                style="margin:0 10px;">if {{ current_col }}=={{ col_position }}
                {%- if col_position == current_col -%}
                  POSITION_IS={{ index }}
                {%- endif -%}
              </p>
            {%- endif -%}
          {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
```

I'm getting p tag value printed as CAPE GUIDE
ABOUT US
CONTACT US

if 1==1

if 1==2

if 1==2

But nothing is being printed from within

```
{%- if col_position == current_col -%}
    POSITION_IS={{ index }}
 {%- endif -%}
```

Seems like pretty much an odd thing to me. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer, It was var type issue.

here  `{% for col_id in (1..5) -%}` I was defining the var as integer and it was comparing with string. That was fixed typecasting the var